# Why is the stack size different in different runs of the same program?

Tags: c, linux, stack

Consider the following program. It takes an argument from command line and then unrolls a recursive function up to that limit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int rec(int x, int limit) {
  if (x == limit) {
    return limit;
  }
  int r = rec(x + 1, limit);
  return r - 1;
}

int main(int arc, char* argv[]) {
  int result, limit;
  limit = atoi(argv[1]);
  printf("stack: %p\n", &result);
  result = rec(0, limit);
  printf("%d\n", result);
}
```

If I compile it I expect it to run out of stack for a fixed input argument limit. Something else happens.

```
dejan@raven:~/test/stack$ gcc stack.c
dejan@raven:~/test/stack$ ./a.out 174580
stack: 0x7fff42fd58f0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
dejan@raven:~/test/stack$ ./a.out 174580
stack: 0x7ffdd2dd8b20
0
```

In two different runs, the stack size seems to be different. It doesn't seem to be a compiler issue as the same thing happens with clang, and the disassembly doesn't involve anything strange.

Why are stack sizes on different runs different?

Comment: [Address space layout randomization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) maybe?

Comment: @Barmar I don't care about the position of the stack, just the size. How would randomization influence the size of the stack?

Comment: I came here to say the same as @Barmar; however, I'm not even sure the address of the first variable declared in your program has much to do with stack position at all; your compiler might not even allocate space of it's own for that variable, and just pass the result in `%EAX` to `printf` directly.

Comment: If you're expecting C programs to crash consistently, don't. There are too many things that might cause buggy programs to behave inconsistently across runs, computers, compilers, etc., and figuring out exactly what causes the inconsistency is rarely helpful.

Comment: @user2357112 There's nothing non-deterministic in his program, it SHOULD behave consistently. It's not dependent on any other state of the system.

Comment: @MarcusMüller True, but it should pass that same `%EAX` every time.

Comment: @Barmar: I'm actually a bit surprised neither gcc nor clang execute the program to determine the result is always `0` and then just drop the execution. Point here is though that we're seeing ASLR in action, but it doesn't explain different recursion depths.

Comment: By the way, with `-O3` it works like a charm, so that solves my confusion why the compiler isn't smart. I didn't tell it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added `/proc/self/maps` parser to your program (same approach as @AndrewHenle advises, but I do it on the start of program, and do not invoke `pmap`):

```
char* get_stack_bounds() {
    FILE* maps = fopen("/proc/self/maps", "r");
    static char line[256];

    while(!feof(maps)) {
        fgets(line, 255, maps);
        if(strstr(line, "[stack]")) {
            char* space = strchr(line, ' ');
            *space = '\0';
            fclose(maps);
            return line;
        }
    }

    fclose(maps);
    return NULL;
}

unsigned long get_stack_right() {
    char* bounds = get_stack_bounds();
    bounds = strchr(bounds, '-') + 1;
    return strtol(bounds, NULL, 16);
}
```

And dump some information in the beginning of `main()`:

```
printf("&result: %p delta: %ld\n", &result, 
     get_stack_right() - ((unsigned long) &result));
```

Here are some results:

```
> ./a.out 104747
&result: 0x7fff3347c7f8 delta: 6152
0
> ./a.out 174580
&result: 0x7fffe43c9b38 delta: 5320
0
> ./a.out 174580
&result: 0x7fff26ad2b28 delta: 9432
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
> ./a.out 174580
&result: 0x7fff145aa5a8 delta: 6744
0
> ./a.out 174580
&result: 0x7fff74fff0b8 delta: 12104
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I think that correlation between `delta` (which is difference between `result` address and base address of stack) and segmentation fault is obvious.

---

You should note that `main()` is not the first function that runs in a program, actual entry point will be `_start()` from crt1.o (or whatever), so initial stack size can differ.

Actual problem is [Address space layout randomization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) .
Here is a comment from `fs/binfmt_elf_fdpic.c` regarding its usage:

```
/* In some cases (e.g. Hyper-Threading), we want to avoid L1 evictions
 * by the processes running on the same package. One thing we can do is
 * to shuffle the initial stack for them, so we give the architecture
 * an opportunity to do so here.
 */
sp = arch_align_stack(bprm->p);
```

Here is implementation of `arch_align_stack()` on x86:

```
unsigned long arch_align_stack(unsigned long sp)
{
    if (!(current->personality & ADDR_NO_RANDOMIZE) && randomize_va_space)
        sp -= get_random_int() % 8192;
    return sp & ~0xf;
}
```

Comment: This is useful! Any idea where the non-deterministic deltas could come from? Is this a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 0):

Add a SIGSEGV handler:

```
void handler( int sig )
{
    char buffer[ 1024 ]
    sprintf( buffer, "/path/to/pmap %d", getpid() );
    system( buffer );
    exit( 0 );
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    signal( SIGSEGV, handler );
       .
       .
       .
```

That way, instead of generating a core file, your process will emit a map of its address space when it SEGVs.

Note that in general that's a pretty dangerous way of doing things.  It's not really async-signal safe.  But you're not doing anything that a deadlock in would cause real damage.

Comment: I am not trying to figure out a way to handle the segfault, the question is about the stack size.

Comment: @DejanJovanović ... which is printed exactly by this `pmap` call.

Comment: Displaying the output from pmap will show you the entirety of the address space of the process.  The information from the address space map would show things like possible address space randomization that could provide you your answer.